# OpenGL - Is switching shaders and uniforms often a serious bottleneck?

Tags: opengl

I'm currently planning out a renderer and I have 2 different ways I could handle shaders. I've written pseduo-code for them:

Example A

```
for all models {
  bind all vertex data for the model
  for each shader on this model {
    set shader
    upload uniforms
    draw indicies for this shader
  }
}
```

Example B

```
for all models {
  collect geometry and seperate it by shader
}
sort geometry by shader into groups
for all shaders {
  set shader
  upload uniforms
  draw geometry group for this shader
}
```

The advantage of Example A is that we only have to upload the vertex data one time and it's shared for all the geometry. The downside of this is I have to constantly change the shader and upload uniforms to it.

The advantage of Example B is that I can sort all the geometry in the entire scene by shader so I only have to apply each shader 1 time for the whole draw. This also means that I will have more on the draw stack at any given time so there is less "idle" time after a drawing for a shader is finished.

Which way would end up being better on performance? Based on what I've read I'm leaning towards Example B but I'd like to learn a little more about it.

Comment: What did your profiling tell you?

Comment: Testing all permutations of scene complexity/shader complexity/geometry complexity and writing both renderers would take an obscene amount of time. I have written Example B in java/opengl but I am now developing in c++/opengl so it would not be really useable for a test case. I was hoping that there was a common practice used or a nice article or just a smart person who knew a lot about this haha.

Comment: It depends on the typical workload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so often with OpenGL it depends on the implementation (=driver) in question.

For example early NVidia drivers were prone for complete shader recompilation when Uniform values changed (so changing a uniform could be much more expensive than switching a texture or shader). Later this bottleneck was removed and changing a uniform value became a rather cheap operation (cheaper than switching a texture or a shader).

As with all performance related questions: You have to profile your program and test out your options.

Comment: Ah was hoping to avoid that. It'll be a lot of work to do both implementations and test them with enough large scenes to get a good result. Though when you say "early nvidia drivers" do you mean like 2007 or 1999?

Comment: @newObjekt: The first drivers to support GLSL and then for some time. That would have been between early 2004 to 2005 IIRC. -- Damn I just realized how much time I've spent using my GeForce 8800 (bought in 2006); it's still not retired, I used it for the past weeks at work as a gap-filler until my workstation would get a new card.

Comment: I think that 2005 is old enough that I can safely say it's not going to be my target hard ware for a game engine. Also I had a Geforce 8600 back in like 2005. That card was awesome haha. IIRC it actually partially melted after 6 years of heavy use.

Comment: @newObjekt: The GeForce8xxx series was released in late October / November 2006 – just nitpicking here.

Comment: Ah yeah I was mostly guessing. It's been a while. Thanks for the advice though.